# No session variables show up in view - Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, session, view, laravel-5.1

I am trying to display errors on my login page using the Session::flash() method in Laravel 5.1.

In my view I am using:

```
@if($errors->has())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
            <div>{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@endif
```

And in my controller:

`return Redirect::route('login')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();`

1. I am not getting anything from the Input::old() method when getting redirected with errors to this page.
2. The `$errors`  variable is empty on the reload.

If I `dd($validator);` right before the `return Redirect::route...`, the $validator has data in it:

[image]

But when the page loads, nothing happens.

I can try `Session::put` but still, nothing happens when getting the view.

What could be wrong? Is there maybe something in `composer` or `php artisan` that may be able to reset this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone that has this problem, how I solved it was changing the `.env` file from `SESSION_DRIVER=array` to `SESSION_DRIVER=file`

Answer (score 0):

`composer` and `php artisan` have got nothing to do with the `Session`.

You are not seeing the `Session::flash` message is because you are not retrieving it.

In order to retrieve a message from `Session::flash`, you need to use the following:

```
@if(Session::has('your_flash_message_key'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <div>{{ Session::get('your_flash_message_key') }}</div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Coming to your view code on `$errors`, try replacing the `@if` with this

```
@if (count($errors) > 0)
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

In [Laravel's official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors) on displaying validation error message(s), it shows the above code only.